# REST API Design: Accept header vs Web browser compatibility

Tags: json, rest, pdf, http-headers

This is a style question about REST API design

I have an API which returns a particular resource, and can return either the fields of the resource as a JSON object, or a PDF representation of the resource. The normal REST way of doing that is to use the same URL, but return either the JSON object or the PDF data depending on the "Accept" header of the request.

This has been fine when calling the API from a client application. But now I am writing a web application, and I want to display the PDF. I can fetch the PDF data with XMLHttpRequest, but there isn't an easy way to display it. (I recall some hack involving passing the whole base64-encoded content in the URL, but that is both flaky and disgusting).

The easy way to display a PDF in a web application is window.open(), but I can't pass an Accept header to that (there are a few questions here for people asking how to do that).

This seems like a potentially common situation. What's the best workaround? Stick ?pdf or /pdf or ?accept=pdf onto the url? Is there a de facto standard? Or is there a solution I haven't thought of (maybe treating "application/pdf" as the default request mime type, and only returning the JSON object if the Accept header is "application/json")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the more I think of it, the more that last idea (return PDF unless explicitly asked for application/json in the Accept header) seems like the right answer. A web browser can display PDFs (at least usually, these days) and not JSON objects, so a request made natively by a browser should always get the PDF, and REST clients that wants JSON data would normally explicitly ask for application/json, so the API server should not do that by default if it has a better browser-compatible form.

Since it took actually explaining this whole problem into the question box to make me think of the answer I posted the question anyway.